# Noether Current when the Lagrangian depends on second derivative of the fields

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, field-theory, noethers-theorem, brst

Let a Lagrangian density for a field theory of $N$ fields $\left\{\phi_i\right\}_{i=1}^N$ be given.

Assume that the Lagrangian density depends on the fields, their spacetime derivatives, *and* their second spacetime derivatives: $\mathcal{L}(\phi_i,\partial_\mu\phi_i,\partial_\nu\partial_\mu\phi_i)$.

Then a short derivation shows that the [Euler-Lagrange equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation#Several_functions_of_several_variables_with_higher_derivatives) are given by:

$$ \frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta\phi_{i}}-\partial_{\mu}\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta\partial_{\mu}\phi_{i}}+\partial_{\nu}\partial_{\mu}\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\phi_{i}}=0 \,\,\, \forall i\in \{1,\dots,N\} $$

Using a similar derivation to the proof of the Noether theorem, I was able to show that the conserved Noether current is:
$$ j^\mu = \sum_{i}\left[\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta\partial_{\mu}\phi_{i}}\Delta\phi_{i}+\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\phi_{i}}\partial_{\nu}\Delta\phi_{i}-\left(\partial_{\nu}\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\phi_{i}}\right)\Delta\phi_{i}\right] $$

My question is: is this correct?

It feels fishy to me because there is a term $\partial_{\nu}\Delta\phi_{i}$ and I would somehow expect all terms to be proportional to $\Delta\phi_{i}$ alone.

I'm doing this to find the conserved Noether current (see [this related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/122929/lagrangian-depends-on-second-derivative-of-field/12293) and [this one which unfortunately had no answers yet](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60255/noether-currents-for-the-brst-tranformation-of-yang-mills-fields)) of the BRST transformation.

Comment: A general expression for equations of motion and canonical stress energy tensor for a Lagrangian with higher derivatives can be found, for example in http://relativity.livingreviews.org/Articles/lrr-2009-4/, paragraph 2.1.1, pp. 11, 12.

Comment: Another reference http://www.rmki.kfki.hu/~lbszab/doc/sparl11.pdf

Comment: @Konstantin Konstantinov: "Not Found." Link seems to have moved to https://link.springer.com/article/10.12942/lrr-2009-4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is correct. I derived and used the same expression in http://vixra.org/abs/1008.0051 page 5 (with one extra term to account for space-time transformations that is not needed for internal symmetries). The dependence on the derivatives $\partial_{\nu}\Delta\phi_{i}$ is necessary and not a problem.