# Noether (quasi)symmetry with jet coordinates?

Tags: symmetry, noethers-theorem

In classical mechanics, there is a symmetry definition for a lagrangian as invariance under 
$$L\rightarrow L+\dfrac{dF(x)}{dt}$$
or even
$$L\rightarrow L+\dfrac{dF(x,\dot{x})}{dt}$$
But, what is the Noether current and procedure when we extended the definition to the whole jet coordinates, beginning with 
$$L\rightarrow L+\dfrac{dF(x,\dot{x},\ddot{x})}{dt}$$
and more generally
$$L\rightarrow L+\dfrac{dF(x,\dot{x},\ddot{x},\ldots)}{dt}$$
where the dots signal the full jet coordinates of the X variable?
What about a jet bundle approach to the two Noether's theorem, even with the local variation trick $\varepsilon (t)$? That is, what are the Noether currents and the local $\varepsilon (t)$ trick extension to jet variables?

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped what I wanted to be answered (I know the answer, included the complicated new formulae, but I just wanted to know if people do it with free coordinate tools or with the full coordinated approach in jet bundles).

Comment: Yes, Noether's theorems work for (quasi)symmetry. Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/387320/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/123098/2451 and links therein.